# Can you build phonegap project without using build.phonegap.com

Tags: cordova

I'm new to phonegap and it's not clear to me whether you are able to build phonegap project on multiple platforms without using their [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com/) site that is limited on number of private apps.

I want to target my apps to Android and iOS, they should be both, free and commercial, but I dont want to be forced to publish them as opensource on github as you can have only 1 private app on free plan and other apps has to be opensource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can go to their [install page](http://phonegap.com/install/) and get the tools to build it yourself for free without having to go through their build service.